# Use libsigc++ with cmake

Tags: cmake, libsigc++

I've found plenty of descriptions which use [pkg-config](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/inkscape/CMakeScripts/Modules/FindSigC++.cmake) or [else](http://code.google.com/p/kpar2kde4/source/browse/trunk/cmake/Findlibsigc.cmake?r=2), but none of them was as easy as for Boost or SDL.
Is there an easier way like this:

```
FIND_PACKAGE( SigC++ REQUIRED )
```

If not what is the best way to use SigC++ with cmake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unless there is a FindSigC++.cmake module. I'd advice you to use pkg-config, because `pkg_check_modules (GLIB2   glib-2.0)` is not that much more difficult.